# Compress/obfuscate URL to use in rewrite?

Tags: http, url, obfuscation

I need to add the URL of a 3rd-party website to a url, but I'd like to compress/obfuscate the host part. Are there any algorithms I can use which will hash the url, but also allow *un-hashing*?

For example; the url is `http://www.twitter.com/myusername`. What I'm serving currently (as a html link) is `http://mysite.net/bounce/www.twitter.com/username`. What I'd *like* to serve is something like `http://mysite.net/bounce/X5nsSkdWfA/username`, and have the bounce script decode `|^/bounce/(.*)/|` back to `www.twitter.com`.

I'd like to do this *without* storing the hash anywhere.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use, for instance, [`ROT13`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) for obfuscating ;-)

```
$ echo twitter.com | rot13
gjvggre.pbz
```

Then you can use [`base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
$ echo twitter.com | base64
dHdpdHRlci5jb20K
```

Naturally, they don't compress. You can come with something yourself for squeezing a few bits out of it.

Comment: The ratio is 1:1 for Rot13 and 3:4 for Base64.

Comment: Gumbo, right, base64 obfuscates better. But then you can roll your own encoder, knowing that host part is case insensitive (1 bit off) and generally can only use a very limited set of characters (too lazy to calculate bit savings).

Comment: Thanks - a little ROT13 with some other magic and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you can use technique exist in this tut..

[BUILDING A URL SHORTENER](http://snook.ca/archives/php/url-shortener)

you can use the function to shortern url and convert it back, by extracting it from url.

Comment: Won't work. I need to do this without storing the hash; that method stores the hash in the DB.